# rsh is removing double quotes

Tags: c, rsh

rsh command is removing the double quotes in the remote shell.

For example:
my command
rsh 10.20.1.25 my_pgm -g "NAME1 NAME2"
In remote shell
my_pgm -g NAME1 NAME2

I want double quotes for -g option in remote shell too. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To escape double quote inside a string use a backslash:

```
rsh 10.20.1.25 my_pgm -g "\"NAME1 NAME2\""
```

> Actually, My C program is like this sprintf(cmd_string, "rsh
>   10.20.1.25 my_pgm -g \"NAME1 NAME2\"");

Ok, you mean using `system()`, see output on `echo`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    system("echo \"NAME1 NAME2\""); /* output: NAME1 NAME2 */
    system("echo '\"NAME1 NAME2\"'"); /* output: "NAME1 NAME2" */

    return 0;
}
```

Translated to yours (Note single quote and double quote around NAME1 NAME2):

`sprintf(cmd_string, "rsh 10.20.1.25 my_pgm -g '\"NAME1 NAME2\"'");`

Or as pointed out by @nos:

```
sprintf(cmd_string, "rsh 10.20.1.25 my_pgm -g \\\"NAME1 NAME2\\\"");
```

Comment: Actually, My C program is like this
sprintf(cmd_string, "rsh 10.20.1.25 my_pgm -g \"NAME1 NAME2\"");
what i should do now?